# How to color special closed curve in CorelDraw or AI?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, corel-draw

I always have problem with coloring closed curves like the following:

[image]

How to color this special closed curve in CorelDraw or AI? Of course I can fill it by some peices but I want unite coloring as I want to use it in animation software.

Comment: The problem is that you have applied a fill to an open path. That's never going to work properly. Make a closed path instead, and add the inside line as a separate path with a stroke and no fill.

Comment: OK. Can you help about this problem: My main curve is an open curve as above but without straight that line … I've just added that straight line for filling the area. Do you have any idea?

Comment: Open paths won't contain a fill properly. Use closed paths for fills instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's better to alter *construction*.

Draw the shape and fill it, and *then* add any internal paths you need.

[image]

One has to envision things as *closed shapes first*. 
Then add any definition based upon internal objects.

---

Your image *seems* to just have a fill applied to the inner curve, like so.....

[image]

You can just remove the fill.

---

If you are trying to add another color there *without* the black stroke on that upper edge, you'll need an *additional shape*..

In Illustrator... Copy the inner path, `Edit > Paste in Back`, `Object > Path > Join` to close the shape. You can then adjust that upper edge if desired. I added a smooth anchor point then made that top edge curve downward....

Remove the stroke, adjust the fill...

[image]

[image]

---

---

---

From comments, it seems you may be trying to fill this...

[image]

If you just add a fill you get and *open path* with a fill, which is bad and should be avoided. Not to mention you can't control what that connecting , non-stroked, edge looks like ....

[image]

So to control what's filled, and have a *closed* shape, copy the path, close it, remove the stroke, add a fill, then adjust...

[image]

It can often be necessary to have a stroke as a *separate object* in order to create a desired appearance. Then merely `group` the two objects afterwards.